# Change authentication wifi WPA to WEPon Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wifi, netsh, wep

I use

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Kites key=phambaoViet

netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

To share WiFi from LAN network on laptop (Windows 8) to my other device.

When I show information `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` the supported authentication is WPA.

My device support authentication WEP only.

How can I change the authentication to WEP?

Infomation:

> Interface name: Wi-Fi
>
> ```
> Driver                    : Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network A dapter
> Vendor                    : Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.
> Provider                  : Microsoft
> Date                      : 03/07/2012
> Version                   : 3.0.0.130
> INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\netathrx.inf
> Files                     : 2 total
>                             C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\athrx.sys
>                             C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vwifibus.sys
> Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
> Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
> FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
> 802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
> Hosted network supported  : Yes
> Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
>                             Open            None
>                             Open            WEP-40bit
>                             Open            WEP-104bit
>                             Open            WEP
>                             WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
>                             WPA-Personal    TKIP
>                             WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
>                             WPA2-Personal   TKIP
>                             Vendor defined  TKIP
>                             WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
>                             Vendor defined  Vendor defined
>                             WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
>                             WPA-Personal    CCMP
>                             WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
>                             Vendor defined  CCMP
>                             WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
>                             Vendor defined  Vendor defined
>                             WPA2-Personal   CCMP
>                             Vendor defined  Vendor defined
> Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
>                             Open            None
>                             Open            WEP-40bit
>                             Open            WEP-104bit
>                             Open            WEP
>                             WPA2-Personal   CCMP
>                             Vendor defined  Vendor defined
> ```

Answer (score 1):

WEP encryption on hostednetwork is not possible. It will run only with WPA. But you can search for third party software which may provide this feature.